Por que o meu HandleException não captura a exeção correta?
Estou trabalhando com o Spring boot a um tempinho, e recentemente comecei a ver tratamento de exceções, porem estou com um problema no meu código que a minha classe esta capturando a exceção mas esta jogando para o tratamento genérico.
Meu service
public PessoasEntity findById(Long id){
    if(personRepository.existsById(id)){
        
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Person with id " + id + " not found");
    }
    return personRepository.findById(id).get();
}

O ResourceNotFoundExcpetion e minha classe de tratamento personalizada.
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String ex) {
        super(ex);
    }
}

Minha classe que captura as exceções
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandle extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
          ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(
                  new Date(),
                  "Eu estou capturando " + ex.getMessage(),
                  request.getDescription(false)
          );
          return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }



    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

A exceção era pra entra no handleNotFoundException porém sempre esta entrando no handleAllExceptions.  Essa minha classe esta anotada com o @ControleAdvice só pra deixar claro.
Versão do Spring 3.2.5, Java 21

seu método personRepository.existsById(id) retorna falso caso encontre um valor para o id? porque se for isso, eu sugiro que mude esse nome de método. nao faz sentido. Caso contrario, ele está seguindo o código com um id que nao existe.

Esse metodo implementei justamente para entra no erro e me retorna a resposta no Postman, porem ainda assim não o retorno era o handleAllExceptions e não a minha exeção personalizada

Segundo essa resposta do SO em inglês, é má prática usar tratamento genérico de exceções, e também já lidei com uma situação similar, e o programa teve o mesmo comportamento.
Todas as exceções herdam da Exception e podem ser capturadas pelo handleAllExceptions. Acredito que o mais adequado seja usar de exceções personalizadas para tratar cada caso.

Downvote merece pelo menos uma explicação. A intenção do SO é manter qualidade de perguntas/respostas, não ser palco pra troll.

Obrigado Gabriel conseguir entender era um erro bobo no parametro do metodo

Certo a sua resposta me ajudou a solucionar o problema , por algum motivo o parametro  HttpStatus status, no metodo handleNotFoundException estava interferindo na chamada do tratamento personalizado do metodo.
Metodo da forma errada
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity handleNotFoundException( HttpStatus status, ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(
new Date(),
ex.getMessage(),
request.getDescription(false));
return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
Agora removendo o HttpStatus status do parametro
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity handleNotFoundException( ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(
new Date(),
ex.getMessage(),
request.getDescription(false));
return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
foi a solução para o problema obrigado.
